# GraphEditPlus VideoInputDevices are missing

Tags: c#, video, webcam, directshow, directshow.net

I am completly new with DirectShow and filters. I was reading some articles, tried some examples with C# and I've used libraries like AForge or DirectShow.NET. I've excluded AForge from my project because of huge latency and bad performance in my project. I've found good example where DirectShow.NET was used and after some refactoring performance of the code was fair enought so I want to try with that.
I couldn't make ISambleGrabber to work so now I'm trying to use GraphEditPlus, connect the graph and generate C# code as example for future use, but...
I cannot find VideoInputDevices filter there, I need to start Previewing and Capturing from webcam, but I cannot find it on the list. It is shown on VLC and is working with AForge and DirectShow.NET.
Mayebe I'm blind or I'm missing something? Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I'm blind - it's named here as Video Capture Sources which I haven't seen before.